Removing eventListener (function with an attribute) in JavaScript
I am working on selection mode in my app (selecting multiple elements to execute some action). It works like this: at default you have a list of elements (decks) which are <a> HTML elements. So, if you click one, it will redirect you to the specific page. There is also a "Select mode" button on the page. After clicking it, redirection is turned off (event.preventDefault), instead selected items are added to an array (selectedDecks) and styling is changed.
The problem is that I do not know how to remove the event listener when I exit selection mode. It still changes the styling etc. instead of redirecting.
Here is the function for toggling between selection mode on/off:
Here is function for toggling between selection mode on/off (I used 'deck.removeEventListener('click', () => handleDeckClick(event, selectedDecks));' here but it does not work):
   function toggleSelectionMode() {
    selectionMode = !selectionMode;
    
    let selectedDecks = [];

    if (selectionMode) {
    selectionModeElements.decks.forEach(deck => {
        deleteSelectedDecksButton.style.transform = "scale(1)"
        deck.style.opacity = "50%";
        deck.addEventListener('click', () => handleDeckClick(event, selectedDecks));
    });
} else {
    selectionModeElements.decks.forEach(deck => {
        deck.removeEventListener('click', () => handleDeckClick(event, selectedDecks));
        deck.style.opacity = "100%";       
        let deckCheck = deck.querySelector(".deck-check");
        deckCheck.style.transform = "scale(0)";
        deck.deckSelection = false;
    });
    selectedDecks = [];
    deleteSelectedDecksButton.style.transform = "scale(0)"; 
}
}

and here is the function for handling clicking a deck (executed as an eventListener):
    function handleDeckClick(event, selectedDecks) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let deck = event.currentTarget;
    let deckCheck = deck.querySelector(".deck-check");
    let deckSelection = deck.deckSelection || false;

    if (deckSelection === false) {
        deck.style.opacity = "100%";
        deckCheck.style.transform = "scale(1)";
        selectedDecks.push(deck.getAttribute('data-deck-id'));
        deck.deckSelection = true;
    } else {
        deck.style.opacity = "50%";
        deckCheck.style.transform = "scale(0)";
        const indexToRemove = selectedDecks.indexOf(deck.getAttribute('data-deck-id'));
        if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
            selectedDecks.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
        }
        deck.deckSelection = false;
    }
}  

Do you have any ideas about what I could use instead of deck.removeEventListener('click', () => handleDeckClick(event, selectedDecks));? Is there a way to simply remove all event listeners from the element without specifying them? Or perhaps I should approach the entire selection mode differently? Thanks for your replies in advance.
